# Google Oauth2 in embedded browser (web view)

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, passport-google-oauth2

I added `Google OAuth2` to my website. I noticed that when the website was opened in a embedded browser (web view), redirecting to google auth page (see the link below) will fail with error:

> "403 disallowed_useragent".

Here is the link:

https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?client_id=813505898895-9vocl0haapnp562pn1hmut2sibregabn.apps.googleusercontent.com&response_type=code&scope=openid%20profile%20email&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.antgora.com%2Fauth1%2Fsign-in%2Fgoogle&state=6515338772758876.%2F

I get that Google no longer allows `OAuth`requests to Google in web view. But here is the strange thing. The google sign in demo 
[developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in](http://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in) work fine when opened in web view. I managed to find the `client_id`and `redirect_uri` used in the demo and replace them into the my google auth link (see the updated link below), the updated link can now magically open in web view.

https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?client_id=831371170934-udapit5jhjj56pft5l2drc9gjhfeclf3.apps.googleusercontent.com&response_type=code&scope=openid%20profile%20email&redirect_uri=storagerelay%3A%2F%2Fhttps%2Fgoogle-developers.appspot.com%3Fid%3Dauth58372&state=6515338772758876.%2F

Notice that I changed only `client_id`and `redirect_url` and nothing else. Later I found more `client_ids`that also works with webview. I am wondering is there any specific settings for these client_ids to work?

Also I want to know what's the recommended fix to:

> "403 disallowed_useragent"?

My website has no native app. And most likely, people will just open the website they received on online chat in a webview. I'd like to avoid showing the :

> "403 disallowed_useragent"

error when they click `*sign-in by Google*`.

Comment: You can use whatever you want as a User-Agent string. You can pretend to be any OS and browser.